# Log in to a website with csrfmiddlewaretoken verification using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to log in to a website with csrfmiddlewaretoken verification, but it throws me the following error:

"csrfmiddlewaretoken = HTML.find_all('input')[1]['value']
IndexError: list index out of range"

What do you think is the problem, I'm new using python :)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request_url = 'https://text.gob.pe/accounts/login/'
with requests.session() as session:
get_url = session.get('https://text.gob.pe/accounts/login/')
HTML = BeautifulSoup(get_url.text, 'html.parser')
csrfmiddlewaretoken = HTML.find_all('input')[1]['value']

#logging in
payload = {
    'next' : '/ profile /',
    'username' : 'secret',
    'password' : 'secret',
    'next': '/ profile /',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrfmiddlewaretoken
}
headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://text.gob.pe/accounts/login/'
}
login_request = session.post(request_url,payload, headers=headers)
home_page = session.get("https://text.gob.pe/ficha/buscar/")
print(home_page.content)
```

Comment: need url, to help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a username and password, it is difficult to show how to proceed. At the moment your mistake is that you didn't specify **headers**

```
headers = {
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

url = "https://logincovid19.minsa.gob.pe/accounts/login/"
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
csrfmiddlewaretoken = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find('input', {'name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'}).get('value')
```

Now **csrfmiddlewaretoken** is something like this - `eyHLYFv7HOYxglzFS9a3JDxOT38u8mrakdwhatOnkvcJJzwN9dNi6olBxJxD1HZi`

I think further the code will look like this, but you need to check it:

```
user = 'YourUserNmaeHere'
password = 'UserPaswordHere'
payload = f'csrfmiddlewaretoken={csrfmiddlewaretoken}&username={user}&password={password}'
response = session.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Ok I have someting xd

https://prnt.sc/ntjx0CxI97EY

How do I know if I'm connected or not?

Comment: @AjaxPain Now u need to bypass the cloudflare. But in this case if u newbee in python best solution is Selenium.

Comment: Or u can try cloudscraper or similar libs to bypass it